# Help with this integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{i\omega t}}{1 + \left(\frac{t^2}{z^2}\right)} dt$ (perpubation theory )

Tags: calculus, physics, quantum-mechanics

I am trying to solve this integral, but I cannot think of an easy way.  Please help!
So the initial problem is this

> Show that if $H^1(t) = -e \varepsilon X/[1+(t/z)^2]$, then, to the first order,
>
> $P_{0 \rightarrow 1} = \frac{e^2 (\varepsilon)^2 (\pi)^2 z^2}{2m\omega \hbar} e^{-2\omega z} $

$X$ is a matrix

So in order to fully solve the problem you need to reduce the integral below.

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{i\omega t}}{1 + \left(\frac{t^2}{z^2}\right)} dt$$

where $i$ is an imaginary number and $\omega$ and $z$ are constants.

Comment: Do you know how to do complex contour integrals? The basic method is to define an upper semicircle around the pole at $t = iz$ then use residues, etc

Comment: I have not heard of complex contour integrals in my life.

Comment: Well that would be helpful to know in the question. Do you only want to use real methods (for a complex integral no less)? What methods do you know to compute the Fourier transform? Do you know any complex calculus? Update the post to include more context, and what you've tried to do.

Comment: I don't think you need to use Fourier transform for this problem.  I have updated the problem.

Comment: I think any real methods will do for my professor.

Comment: There's more than one way to solve it, but again, it depends on what you know. And the Fourier transform is just the integral itself, you're not using it so solve the integral; the integral *is* a Fourier transform.

Comment: So far I haven't try anything fancy yet.   I just use my calculus knowledge.  I tried a series expansion on $(1 + \frac{t^2}{z^2})$ .  No results

Comment: I solved it using the Cauchy distribution!  All is good!